# Using GitHub our Master branch is broken with the latest check-in, How do I have my local master set to a prior check-in?

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

The master branch of our GitHub repository is broken with the latest check-in.  Unfortunately, I pulled in the latest master check-in to my local copy.  Someone else is working on the fix for the broken master check-in.  I just want to update my local master copy to be the files from the check-in prior to the broken check-in so I can build successfully locally.  I am using Visual Studio to pull/push, etc.

Master Check-in #10 successful build
Master Check-in #11 build is broken  /  local master has been updated to this check-in

How can I change my local copy of master to be set to the check-in #10?  Later on, I will update my local copy of master to check#12 when the fix is add by someone else.  I am not the one who will revert any changes to master.  I just want my local copy of the master to be set to check-in #10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Checkout `master`
- `git log`
- Copy the commit `<hash>` for the previous check-in.
- `git checkout <hash>`

You should now be checked out at the point of that previous check-in. Once the fix has been pushed, you may have to `cherry-pick` any changes you have to a new branch off of the latest `master`.

Comment: If I checkout in master from a prior check-in locally on my machine and then create a new branch from my local master, will the new branch include any code changes from the bad check-in?

Comment: Once you've checked out a specific commit, any new branches should start at that point. So the "bad check in" code, won't exist at that state of the repo.